# mySQL table creation query syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

// Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with this MySQL query syntax ?

```
String createTableSQL = ""
                + " CREATE TABLE location("
                + " location_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " location_name VARCHAR(30),"
                + " addr VARCHAR(30),"
                + ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the last   change AUTOINCREMENT in AUTO_INCREMENT  and add PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`)

```
 String createTableSQL = ""
            + " CREATE TABLE location("
            + " location_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            + " location_name VARCHAR(30),"
            + " addr VARCHAR(30),"
            + " PRIMARY KEY (`location_id `))";
```

Comment: I removed , maybe I have few mistakes so it didn't help at this time.

Comment: Great, thank you @Mike. It helped, table is created.